# Websphere Message Broker and Websphere Transformation Extender Installation

Tags: messaging, messagebroker, bus, broker

I am having issues making WMB and WTX work together on Windows environment. All the installations seem to have successfully installed.

Now, when i add a WTX node in a Message Flow, i get 2 exceptions:

1. java.lang.NullPointerException at com.ibm.websphere.dtx.WTXPlugIn.BrowseLocalCompiledMap.checkCompiledMap(Unknown Source)
2. java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/ibm/websphere/dtx/WTXPlugIn/WTXPlugInStringResources

I did some search on this and discovered the first issue is supposed to be fixed in one of the fix packs. I got the fix pack and uninstalled and re-installed everything, but i get the same results.

Below are the Versions i am using:

1. WMB 8.0.0.1 (8.0 with FIX Pack 1) 64 Bit
2. WTX for Integration Servers 8.4.0.3 64 Bit
3. WTX Design Studio 8.4.0.3 32 Bit (I dont think this matters, but just listing here)
4. WMQ 7.5

Has anyone made this combination work? Any thoughts or comments are welcome and appreciated.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought i will finally update the final resolve on this question.

I had to open a PMR with IBM and they directed me to 8.4.0.4 for WTX. 8.4.0.3 64 bit installations has some bugs which were fixed with 8.4.0.4.

Answer (score 0):

Is the complete stack available in the error? It would be useful to see where in WMB code that exception is being raised from. I assume this is during deployment of a bar file containing a WTX node?

Comment: Thanks for responding, Dave! By complete stack, i assume you mean other nodes available in message flow. If yes, other nodes are not in error. Only the WTX node gives the errors.        The errors are during adding a WTX Node in message flow. (Not during deployment, but while adding the node itself).  The errors are from "Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in:" "org.eclipse.ui.views.properties.tabbed" -- java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.ibm.websphere.dtx.WTXPlugIn.BrowseLocalCompiledMap.checkCompiledMap

Comment: This is in WMB Toolkit

Comment: This looks to be an issue with the WTX side installation, I'm afraid my expertise lies more in the WMB side but there are a few things you can check: In the windows registry check that HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\IBM\WebSphere TranformationExtender\8.4\DTXHOME points to the WTX Design Studio install dir. You could also try raising a PMR with WTX and asking them if you need an "eclipsebridge" patch.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to those registry settings. I checked them and they all looked good.